# Remove Attach File icon from ribbon

Tags: attachments

When a user enters a new record or edits a record, there is a option in "EDIT" tab called Attach File. How do I disable that so users don't see that action Attach File when they try to input a new record or edit a record.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Attachments. Check, Disabled in  "Attachments to list items are"

Comment: @MattLudwig, you can mark it as answer, then :-)